# mockResolvedValueOnce works with await but mockRejectedValueOnce doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, axios, jestjs

I am working on my test for a new project and have them set up but am running into an async issue with jest.

I start with `jest.mock('axios');`

And the working test is

```
it('Dispatches SNACK_BAR after submitting ForgotPassword', async () => {
    let store = configureStore({ reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      snackBar: snackBarReducer
    }})

    axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({headers: {
      authorization: 'asdasdasdas'
    },
    status: 200});

    await store.dispatch(forgotPasswordActions.forgotPasswordPost('test@test.com', (path) => {}))
    expect(store.getState().snackBar).toEqual({"message": "Check your email for a reset link", "severity": "success", "timestamp": store.getState().snackBar.timestamp});
  });
```

But when I try the fail case

```
it('Dispatches SNACK_BAR after submitting ForgotPassword with an error', async () => {
    let store = configureStore({ reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      snackBar: snackBarReducer
    }})
    
    axios.post.mockRejectedValueOnce({response: {headers: {
        authorization: 'asdasdasdas'
      },
      status: 500,
      data: {
        error: 'Error'
    }}});

    await store.dispatch(forgotPasswordActions.forgotPasswordPost('test@test.com', (path) => {}))
    expect(store.getState().snackBar).toEqual({"message": "Error", "severity": "error"});
  })
```

The expect doesn't wait for the dispatch to resolve. If I change the mockRejectedValueOnce to mockResolvedValueOnce then I get a similar result to the first test. It seems the only difference is mockRejectedValueOnce but I am not sure why

```
export const forgotPasswordPost = ({ email }, navigate) => async dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/password`,
  { "user": { email: email }})
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Check your email for a reset link", "success"]})
  })
  .catch(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Error", "error"]});
  })
}
```

The function that is being tested

Comment: I suspect the issue is your action creator `forgotPasswordActions.forgotPasswordPost`. could you post its code too?

Comment: Sure 
```export const forgotPasswordPost = ({ email }, navigate) => async dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/password`,
  { "user": { email: email }})
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Check your email for a reset link", "success"]})
  })
  .catch(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Error", "error"]});
  })
}``` updated the post also for better formatting

Answer (score 1):

In `forgotPasswordPost`  you return async function `async dispatch => {}`. This function has to return a promise. But currently it is void

```js
/// original function
export const forgotPasswordPost = ({ email }, navigate) => async dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/password`,
  { "user": { email: email }})
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Check your email for a reset link", "success"]})
  })
  .catch(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Error", "error"]});
  })
}

/// Try to to return THE Promise, not you return the axios.post promise chain
export const forgotPasswordPost = ({ email }, navigate) => async dispatch => {
  return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/password`,
  { "user": { email: email }})
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Check your email for a reset link", "success"]})
  })
  .catch(response => {
    return dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Error", "error"]});
  })
}


/// ANother proposal using async await
export const forgotPasswordPost = ({ email }, navigate) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/password`, { "user": { email: email }});
     dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Check your email for a reset link", "success"]})
  } catch (e) {
     dispatch({ type: SNACK_BAR, payload: ["Error", "error"]});
  }
}
```